# iOS Mapping Application New View from Annotation

Tags: ios

I am totally new to iOS development, and am creating a mapping application for a local river. The point of the application is to allow users to map out a route on the river by selecting different points. I am using MapKit to work on this, but have run into some issues. My main issue is how to add a button to an annotation so that once clicked, a detail window will open and the user can learn more about the point as well as add it to the trip. Here's my code, any thoughts will help!

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CoreLocation/CLLocation.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end



@implementation ViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.mapView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{


// Add an annotation
MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];


point.coordinate = userLocation.coordinate;
point.title = @"Where am I?";
point.subtitle = @"I'm here!!!";

[self.mapView addAnnotation:point];


point.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(33.62258872997,-86.599988937378);
point.title = @"Civitan Park";
point.subtitle = @"Trussville, AL";
[self.mapView addAnnotation:point];




}



@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your map view delegate should implement `–mapView:viewForAnnotation:` and return an annotation view that has one of its accessory view properties set. The normal thing is to set the `rightCalloutAccessoryView` property to a `UIButton` whose type is `UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure`. You map delegate should also implement `-mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:`, which will be called when the user taps the button in the accessory view. You can then push a detail view controller onto the navigation stack, or whatever else you like.